# Changing color of HighlightBrushKey in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, colors

I have the following problem.

The background color in a ListView is set LightGreen or White, whether a boolflag is true or false.

[Example Screen](http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/133/listview.jpg)

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BoolFlag}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Personen}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ListViewSelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Vorname}" Header="Vorname" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Nachname}" Header="Nachname" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Alter}" Header="Alter" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BoolFlag}" Header="BoolFlag" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Window1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private IList<Person> _personen = new List<Person>();

    public Window1()
    {
        _personen.Add(new Person 
                {
                    Vorname = "Max",
                    Nachname = "Mustermann",
                    Alter = 18,
                    BoolFlag = false,
                });

        _personen.Add(new Person 
                {
                    Vorname = "Karl",
                    Nachname = "Mayer",
                    Alter = 27,
                    BoolFlag = true,
                });

        _personen.Add(new Person 
                {
                    Vorname = "Josef",
                    Nachname = "Huber",
                    Alter = 38,
                    BoolFlag = false,
                });

        DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IList<Person> Personen
    {
        get
        {
            return _personen;
        }
    }

    private void ListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = e.AddedItems[0] as Person;

        if (person != null)
        {
            if (person.BoolFlag)
            {
                this.Resources[SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Resources[SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.RoyalBlue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Person.cs:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Vorname { get; set; }

    public string Nachname { get; set; }

    public int Alter { get; set; }

    public bool BoolFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to set the highlight color of the selected item, depending on the boolflag.
In Code-Behind I do this with:

```
private void ListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = e.AddedItems[0] as Person;

        if (person != null)
        {
            if (person.BoolFlag)
            {
                this.Resources[SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Resources[SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.RoyalBlue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but now I want to define the code above in the XAML-file.

With

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
```

I can overwrite the default-value. However, it works, but the color is set to Green for all selected items. I have tried different ways to switch the color of HighlightBrushKey between Green and Blue in XAML, depending on the boolflag, but I didn't succeed.

May you can help me and give me some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why highlightBrushKey is not so flexible. For a similar reason i switched on to an alternative way of setting the selected items background color by making using of its border. You can take a look at this http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/06/28/background-color-for-wpf-listbox-selected-item.aspx

Comment: Made my day :)
Thank you!
I was too focused on that HighlightBrushKey and I thought too complex. Now it works.